# Docker container cannot resolve request to service in another container

Tags: networking, docker

I'm running **gitlab-ce** and **gitlab-ci-multi-runner** in separated docker containers, but on the same server.

Gitlab CE works fine, I can access it via browser and clone projects using both http and ssh.

However my runner cannot connect to Gitlab using domain/server ip. It can connect to it only via local docker network (for example using ip address 172.17.0.X or, if linked, by using service alias).

Ping to domain/server ip returns response.

I tried to link it as **gitlab:example.domain.com** but it didn't work, as somehow runner resolved server ip address instead of local network address

```
 Checking for builds... failed: couldn't execute POST against http://example.domain.com/ci/api/v1/builds/register.json: Post http://example.domain.com/ci/api/v1/builds/register.json: dial tcp server.ip:80: i/o timeout
```

@Edit

docker-compose.yml

```
gitlab:
  image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:8.2.2-ce.0
  hostname: domain.name 
  privileged: true
  volumes:
    - ./gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab
    - ./gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab
    - ./gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab
  restart: always
  ports:
    - server.ip:22:22
    - server.ip:80:80
    - server.ip:443:443
runner:
  image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - ./runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I have no clue what's the issue here.
I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please share your docker commands you use to run the containers.

Comment: Added **docker-compose.yml**. I am running this things using `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: What is the IP and port that runner uses to connect to gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a firewall problem. Unlocking **docker0** interface allowed traffic from containers :)